# Pre-compile expandable macro

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros

I'm trying to save some time / make my code readable.  I have a lot of 'isXXX' messages that return BOOL.  I am constantly adding more 'is' messages.  Is it possible to make a macro that's expandable at pre-compile time via a list.

I want to specify:
isMacro(1, 2, 3).

And for each of those, I want the macro to expand it into a full -(BOOL)is1 {...}, -(BOOL)is2...

It seems like this would be a good use of the precompiler macro expansion, but I'm not sure how to implement the isMacro(...) part. (Specifically, the ... that expands into full functions before compile).

--- Update:

The 'is' methods are all dynamically computed, but they are all common.

I'm testing a single variable against an enum value and determining whether it's equal.  I can't @synthesize them, because it's dynamic. I have all of them in a @property for convenience. I just want something that's like @synthesize, where I can list all of them, and create a dynamic response for each isXXX method.

Also, I don't want to run isCheck:(opMode)mode, since there is no pre-compile checking to make sure it's a valid enum value.

All of the is functions are in the following format:
`-(BOOL) isTurtle { return operationMode == Turtle; }` The key is that I want it to function as a property for simplicity. Therefore, I don't want something like is:(opMode)mode, where I have to specify `BOOL res = [obj is:Tutle];`

Comment: Is this for C++, Objective-C, or C?  You've tagged all three languages here.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?   `-(BOOL)is1 {...}, -(BOOL)is2...` is not valid C code so why do you want a macro that evaluates to that?

Comment: @David: So actually, you're in Objective-C. If you're working in a language, tag that language. Do not tag other languages because you guess that it might maybe be applicable to them.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is not at all clear. Please expand.  What are the items that you are testing? Why do you have so many similar tests? Please at least post one of these methods as an example.

Comment: Yeah seriously.  This question was tagged "c" and I know a lot about C, but the this turned out to be a poorly explained question about objective C so I wasted my time looking at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), the [BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/repeat_from_to.html) macro should suit your need.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat_from_to.hpp>

#define IS_METHODS(depth, n, aux) -(BOOL)is ## n { return aux == n; } 

@implementation Foo
BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(1, 31, IS_METHODS, operationMode)
@end
```

If you can't, you're out of luck. Implementing BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO is about the same effort as just writing the 30+ functions directly.

Also I don't see how `[obj isMode:12]` is really worse than `obj.is12`. The former also allows a variable mode, and is less cryptic to other programmers (think about the maintenance effort).

Comment: @David: Are you allowed to use Boost? ([Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to be precise.)

Comment: Can't.  But you're spot on.  I'm looking for Boost's "local iteration" functionality.